# Self hosted wordpress site super slow to resolve with dynamic dns on macOS

Tags: macos, dns, apache-http-server, mysql, self-hosting

I host a developpement wordpress site on my Mac Mini with Mojave. I used to work with MAMP and thought it was the culprit but it's not, I get the same behaviour. I stripped down my install, removed MAMP and enabled apache 2.4.34 for php and installed mysql 8.0.2 for the database.

everything is setup properly with NO-IP.com

In my hosts file I have virtual dns set up like this:

127.0.0.1 loalhost

127.0.0.1 mydomain.ddns.net

IP adress of the computer is managed by a dynamicdns feature on my router/modem. ports 80 and 443 are redirected to the mini server

This is exactly what I noticed :

When my computer is connected via LAN to the router it takes 40sec at least to resolve the adress mydomain.ddns.net. Once the url is resolved it loads fast. But every page url to mydomain.ddns.net takes 30sec to a minute to resolve.

When I unplug my LAN cable to the router, it's resolved right away and load the page almost instantly.

Maybe it's a coincidence, but I don't see significant difference when it comes to a plain simple php or html page. Maybe it's coming from the SQL side of the website.

Another clue : I can't connect to mydomain.ddns.net from another computer on the same network. It gives timeouts. I must use my phone with LTE to check the website from "outside".

Do you have any idea what could be the culprit and how to get my website working fast in any situation?

Thanks a lot for your help

take care

Damien

Answer (score 1):

I investigated widely, from apache modules, mysql database errors, to php and js bugs... and I found out, thanks to the very useful plugin "Query Monitor",  that their was an API request to paypal sandbox causing the issue. (30sec long).
The culprit was "WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway" plugin.  I need to check that in details.

I come from about 40sec loading time to 1.5sec. Huge difference!

So for everyone looking to find the problem with server timeouts on wordpress and not with a single php or html page, install "query monitor" and look at all the flagged errors. (you need to login and enable the top WP toolbar in the user menu)
errors will be displayed in this top toolbar.

BUT, I still wonder why I can't visit the website from another device inside my local network. I have timeouts still. Any clue?

thanks a lot

Comment: *"I still wonder why I can't visit the website from another device inside my local network."* - It sounds like your router may not support [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (NAT loopback). Using entries in your `hosts` file can work around this but only effect the device with that modified `hosts` file. If you want local resolution for all your devices without modifying their individual `hosts` files, you'll likely need to set up a local DNS server to resolve the domain you wish to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did not know anything about hairpinning. I'll check if my router is capable of doing that. If not, nevermind. thanks take care.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope everything works out to your satisfaction. You take care as well. =)